How can I get my challenge reopened?
This question is closed as off-topic.
I am really angry that my recent edits have not been successful in reopening the question.
So, I am waiting for a satisfactory edit to reopen this question. How to get this re-opened?
I have asked this question on November 29 when the Code Golf site is the Today's Featured Site. I have spent the last few days making more edits with the question, but I am angry that my edits are not helping to reopen the question. Can you suggest any edit that will reopen the question?

In addition to rydwolf's answer, I'd like to add in a response elaborating on my comment under the challenge:

I've voted not to reopen this question, for two reasons. Firstly, as pointed out, this needs an objective scoring criteria to have any chance of being reopened. But, more importantly, the "Solution Approach". Not only is this an unobservable requirement (how are you confirming people are using e.g. binary search?) but it indicates heavily to me that this is a homework question, or otherwise non-original, as requiring this style of specific steps to solving the challenge is a classic hallmark of those questions.

The site reguarly receives questions/challenges that are people attempting to "outsource" their homework assignments, other competitive coding sites' challenges, and so on: so-called non-original challenges.
First and foremost, I am not accusing you of doing this. I am simply remarking that a lot of the requirements you've included in your post (and in previous revisions) are commonly included in these kind of posts (restricting to a single, commonly used language; requiring specific steps to solve; requiring specific, clunky in/output formats; etc.). And these kind of posts are not welcome on our site, as we require all work to be appropriately attributed to the original author.
My biggest recommendations for getting your challenge open would be to:

Add in an objective scoring criteria (I'd suggest code-golf),
Remove this "Solution Approach" section, as it is not only unobservable, but also indicates towards a style of post you don't want it to indicate to, and
Open the challenge to all languages. There's almost no reason I can see for why the challenge should be Python-specific, so why restrict other languages from competing?

I'd also suggest loosening the input/output formats into more classic decision-problem and date options, although this one is more a matter of preference.
Finally, I'd recommend against getting angry. Your revision comments are understandable, but not nice, and we expect everyone to try to be nice on the site. We're aware it can be a bit of an uphill struggle to ask a good, original challenge first time, but it doesn't help anyone to get angry about the process.

The question is still not reopening. What do I do next?

Disclaimer: I have not previously seen or interacted with your question, and was not a close voter

CGCC (this site) has unusually strict requirements compared to other sites, and operates much differently. Aside from tips questions, which have special rules (which are also difficult to follow, just more subtly), all questions are challenges, which must meet a few conditions:

They typically have to involve writing and submitting code
They need well-written and precise rules for what a submission is supposed to do
They need to have an objective winning criterion: a way of scoring submissions which can rank them from most to least competitive, typically in per-language categories for fairness. This is typically code-golf (fewest bytes of code wins), but we have others like fastest-code and king-of-the-hill. Before posting a challenge with an unusual winning criterion, be sure to check a few more recent highly voted questions in the category, since most have special requirements for a well-defined challenge

Here's my analysis of your question as it's currently written:

Objective: This is well-written, but you should clarify some edge cases (can the start and end dates of two events overlap, or can there be no overlap whatsoever?), and there is a high chance this challenge is a duplicate of an existing one (a challenge doesn't have to be precisely the same to be counted as a dupe, it just needs to be ~90% similar in how you would solve it. E.g., any challenge that's just "print this song's lyrics as short as possible" is considered a duplicate of our rickroll challenge)
Input/Output: Your I/O format is a little strict for more modern challenges, which tend to be looser (e.g., allowing different date formats, making the leading number of dates optional, allowing the dates as an array rather than newline-delimited string, allowing more ways of indicating "not possible" such as an error or null). Also, requiring that answers support up to n=100,000 is nonstandard, since it only really restricts unusual (=interesting, in most cases) approaches or approaches in unusual languages
Language restriction: Restricting to a single language (Python) is highly discouraged
Objective winning criterion: No objective winning criterion is specified. If two different people create a solution to the challenge, who wins? (Remember, this site is for competitive coding)

In the future, if you haven't already, I recommend checking out the sandbox, which we highly recommend askers use to identify any issues with their challenges before posting. Writing a good challenge is hard! Even users who have written thousands of them use the sandbox regularly.

Action items: I would recommend loosening your I/O requirements slightly, removing the Python-only restriction, and choosing an objective winning criterion (I strongly recommend code-golf). Make sure to look at some similar recent challenges to get an idea of what your fixed question should look like, and once you submit an edit, it will be bumped on the homepage and in the reopen votes review queue (feel free to comment on this answer too, and I can let some people know in chat if it looks good). If you have challenge ideas in the future, check out the sandbox and we'll help iron out any issues before it goes live!
